# How to turn in and off the #+INCLUDE on org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

I have many lines that include external files in my main .org file. Sometimes I need to export the main file to pdf (and latex) without including the external files. So, I would like to know how to efficiently turn in and off lines that include external file that uses the #+INCLUDE: command in my main .org file.

Comment: Would using `org-export-exclude-tags` as described here: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-export.html#sec-9 help?